# Using git, upload new directory after deleting the existing subdirectories to Github without removing the currently deleted dir. from Github

Tags: git, github, git-subtree

I have **folder A** (git initialized) which has two more **folders 1 and 2**, and these two folders have some files in them. very first time I did `add commit push` to the master branch and everything is visible on Github.

[image]

Now, I deleted **folder 1** (from local) and created another **folder 3** (with some files inside it).

My question is, **How to push only folder 3 to GitHub without deleting folder 1 from there?** I was hoping to use subtree but forcing the push with subtree command leads to overwriting of folders/files in the GitHub and only content of **folder 3** is visible.

```rb
git push origin `git subtree split --prefix 3 master`:master --force
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, this is not how Git works and it is not possible through Git.

Comment: You don't push folders, you push commits. If you don't want to delete folder `1`, you must not make a commit where it is missing. That means eventually that you must not delete it locally, either.

Comment: Is it possible to commit only folder 3 and merge it with rest of the folders remotely? @j6t

Comment: No. That’s not what Git is.

Answer (score 1):

While making a commit, we can be specific about the files which we want to commit.

Below commands will add only folder 3 changes to commit and push it to Github.

git add 3
git commit -m "Adding folder 3"
git push

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. this works in a way that only folder 3 is being staged and so on but since git is also tracking deleted files, its objects folder continue to grow and there is no way to make git permanently forget about the deleted files without messing up the objects folder in .git dir. any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, We can use .gitignore file to remove folder/files from tracking in .git  . We can run  $git rm -r --cached 1/  and maunally create .gitignore in base directory with content "1/"      //not sure whether this helps your requirement.

Comment: thanks, Vinayagam, after reading about git and how it tracks the file I realized it is not possible to achieve it through Git.